# Alter template source programmatically with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple piece of code, that replace the `ng-include` tag with a proper template based on the button that I click (here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KqwP07fDZSZta9Kiswc6?p=preview)):

```
<button ng-click="template='page1'">Show Page 1 Content</button>
<button ng-click="template='page2'">Show Page 2 Content</button>

<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1">
  <h1 style="color: blue;">This is the page 1 content</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page2">
  <div id="testanglr" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

What I want to do is to replicate the same behaviour of *Show Page 2 Content* button with a javascript function (rather than Angular's HTML helper tag). 
Regarding the Plunker linked above, I would that the third button will act exactly as the second button, but this behavior should be executed inside the `onClickHandler` function in place of alert.

Comment: Your example is pretty simple, please correct if I´m wrong, but I guess that what you are trying to do in the real world is to use a third party js application to change that template, is that it? If that´s the case, please let us know so we can solve this in a more angular way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to change angular from outside of angular world. You can do it this way:

```
function onClickHandler() {
  var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=plunker]');
  var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
  appScope.template = 'page2';
  appScope.$apply();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WKLJ45yRYu1583C2ZnfT

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want like this but there is a way to achieve this.

**JS**

```
function onClickHandler() {

  var ele = document.getElementById("main");
  angular.element(ele).scope().template='page1';
  angular.element(ele).scope().$apply();
}
```

If you are using jQuery then directly you can use `$("#main")` instead of `angular.element`. In angular.element, we need to use `DOM` element only. we can't use ID selector or class selector as it has been removed from jqlite by angular.
[Updated Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HWdGe3fB0i969K7nYtk?p=preview)